# Move images based on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a section where I have two Images

```
<img class="first">
<img class="second">
```

the first image is left aligned and the second one is right
I want to move them from right to left and left to right based on scroll
When the user scrolls down images should move to the center from left and right

Here is the code pen link: https://codepen.io/taruunn/pen/RwjQrOy

Comment: The codepen already shows a working solution, no?

Comment: No, timing should be the same when user scroll I tried but Can't achieve

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean on scroll event, the images #1 and #4 should move at the same time?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add key at `.add()`. This code, I add `"first"`.

So it will move together.

Apply the code below.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var scrollHorizontal = new TimelineLite()
  .add(TweenMax.to("#scrollHorizontal1", 1, {x:'-100%'}), "first")
  .add(TweenMax.to("#scrollHorizontal2", 1, {x:'100%'}), "first");

var horizontalScroll = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#scrollHorizontal",
  triggerHook: 'onLeave',
  duration: 3000
}).setTween(scrollHorizontal).setPin("#scrollHorizontal").addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Awsome your code works.